# How to get elasticsearch-transport-couchbase to work with ES5 + X-Pack security

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, xdcr

I'm working on transitioning from ES 1.7 to 5.x and I'm having a problem with the elasticsearch-transport-couchbase plugin. It did work with ES 1.7 with Shield, and the credentials it used were specified in the elasticsearch.yml file:

```
shield.user: "username:password"
```

The shield.user parameter is no longer supported in ES 5.x and I can't find anywhere on the documentation how to set this up. Has anyone done a Couchbase XDCR to ES 5.x with X-Pack security? Anyone knows how to set this up?

Thanks,
Yosi

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Support for X-Pack security was added in version 4.0 of the [Couchbase Elasticsearch Connector](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-elasticsearch-connector).

Disclaimer: I am a Couchbase employee developing the Elasticsearch connector.

Comment: so if we are on elasticsearch 5.6.7 and plugin 3.0.1 we are out of luck?

Comment: and why cant I see this github issue? it give 404 https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-elasticsearch-connector/issues/170

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Unfortunately that's correct; the architecture of plugin 3.x is not compatible with ES security.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Sorry about that broken issue link. When the connector was promoted from the `couchbaselabs` incubator organization over to `couchbase`, all of the open issues were migrated to the [Couchbase Jira](https://issues.couchbase.com/projects/CBES/) and the GitHub issue tracker was disabled. I did a quick search and didn't see a reference to GitHub issue 150 in Jira, so maybe it got closed before the migration? Feel free to file a new issue in Jira if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

that parameter moved to `xpack.security.user` - I have no idea however, if the couchbase plugin is compatible with ES 5.x (you need to have a specific version of the plugin)

Comment: I was not aware of this option. When adding it in, it seems like it "disabling" xpack security (any simple GET requests succeeds without authentication). I assume the couchbase plugin would also work but I'm not even testing it because that solution would still not be good as it defeats the purpose of having xpack security.

Regarding the plugin version, I got the one relevant to my ES version (plus it works when xpack security is disabled). I'm hoping someone who already has that configured would see this and share the correct config...

Comment: I think you cant just add one line, either you have no xpack config or full in yml